# Onto function between $M \otimes_{A} L$ and $N \otimes_{A} L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm trying to prove the following statement, but I'm having so much trouble with it.

Let $L, M$ y $N$ modules over a ring $A$. Assume that exist an onto application of $A$-module between $M$ and  $N$. Show that exist an onto application of $A$-module between $M \otimes_{A} L$ and $N \otimes_{A} L$.

Could someone helpe me with it, any hint or any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Start with trying to imagine which function $M \otimes_{A} L\to N \otimes_{A} L$ we're actually talking about here. _Then_ try to prove it is onto.

Comment: I mean the function must be $m \otimes l \to n \otimes l$ but i dont how to follow

Comment: How would you _usually_ prove that a map is onto?

Comment: Taking any element on $N \otimes_A L$ and showing that has a preimage

Comment: yes – and what does an arbitrary element of $N\otimes_AL$ look like?

Comment: something like this $x=\sum_{i} x_{i} \otimes b_{i}$ para $x_{i} \in N , b_{i} \in L$

Comment: correct. now, since the given map $M\to N$ (call it $\alpha$) is onto, we know that for each $x_i$ there is $m_i\in M$ with $\alpha(m_i)=x_i$. now can you see how to finish?

Comment: No, still dont see it, how do I put together these two applications?

Comment: can you see that each $x_i\otimes b_i$ lies in the image of the map you've defined? for definitness call that map $\bar{\alpha}$. by definition you've defined $\bar{\alpha}$ by extending the action $m\otimes l\mapsto \alpha(m)\otimes l$ for each $m\in M$ and $l\in L$. so can you find something in $M\otimes_A L$ that maps to $x_i\otimes b_i$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136575/discussion-between-alek-murt-and-atticus-stonestrom).